# Exact website links from google through BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to search google using BeautifulSoup and open the first link. But when I opened the link it shows error. The reason i think is that because google is not providing exact link of website, it has added several parameters in url. How to get exact url?

When i tried to use **cite** tag it worked but for big urls its creating problem.

The first link which i get using soup.h3.a['href'][7:] is:
'http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/White_holes&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi_oYLLm_rUAhWJNI8KHa5SClsQFggbMAI&usg=AFQjCNGN-vlBvbJ9OPrnq40d0_b8M0KFJQ'

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=site:wikipedia.com+Black+hole&gbv=1&sei=YwHNVpHLOYiWmQHk3K24Cw')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.h3.a['href'][7:])
```

Comment: There may be a better solution, but if the issue is that Google is appending parameters beginning always with a "&" and there's never a "&" before the link you can try slicing it: `soup.h3.a['href'][7:soup.h3.a['href'].find('&')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the returned string:

```
url = soup.h3.a['href'][7:].split('&')
print(url[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

hope by clubbing all answer together presented above ,your code will look like 
this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import os
import time

url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:wikipedia.com+Black+hole&dcr=0&gbv=2&sei=Nr3rWfLXMIuGvQT9xZOgCA"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

url1 = "https://www.google.co.in"

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
get_details = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"g"})
final_data = []
for details in get_details:
    link = details.find_all("h3")
    #links = ""
    for mdetails in link:
        links = mdetails.find_all("a")
        lmk = ""
        for lnk in links:
            lmk = lnk.get("href")[7:].split("&")
            sublist = []
            sublist.append(lmk[0])
        final_data.append(sublist)

filename = "Google.csv"
with open("./"+filename, "w")as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0, len(final_data)):
        csvfile.writerow(final_data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler. You're looking for this:

```py
# instead of this:
soup.h3.a['href'][7:].split('&')

# use this:
soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "site:wikipedia.com black hole",     # query
  "gl": "us",                               # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                                # language    
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(first_link)

# https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Primordial_black_hole
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to extract the data from the structured JSON rather than figuring out why things don't work and then maintain it over time if some selectors will change.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "site:wikipedia.com black hole",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] - first index of search results
first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Primordial_black_hole
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.